# How to add data to a nested object in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my current Firestore in Firebase.
[image]

I need help adding data to the `savedSearches` map.

I need to use `.set()` (because a users `savedSearches` might not exist).

My current attempt looks like this:

```
database.collection('users').doc(uid).set({savedSearches: data}, {merge: true})
```

But this doesn't add an object within `savedSearches` with a unique ID.

When I was using Firebase Realtime Database I was just doing this:

```
database.ref('users/' + uid + '/savedSearches').push(data)
```

And that worked perfectly. How can I do that in Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your document contains an array field, you can use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements. `arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. `arrayRemove()` removes all instances of each given element.

```
database.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
    savedSearches: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This somehow works even when savedSearches isn't already defined, which I thought weren't possible with .update()